# List of Laplace transform differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, big-list

I’ve been starting to learn about solving differential equations using the Laplace transform, and I wanted good, non obvious examples.
I think this can help beginners(like me) get where it is applicable.
Also, non obvious calculations of the Laplace transform will be nice.

Comment: @Moo yes. For the most part, but these aren’t novel examples and if I see them the way to the solution is pretty obvious

Comment: hi, did you find some good resource, e.g. book, or website etc?

Comment: No, not really.

Comment: too bad :p @razivo